# Antonym of "perfect, flawless" with the meaning that *everything* is faulty

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Example:

Peter got a perfect/flawless/impeccable score: 0 errors for 100 questions.

John got a ? score: 100 errors for 100 questions (Yes, he filled out the questions. And probably smudged with the extra benefit of grammatical and spelling errors in hen scratching).

The problem with "normal" antonyms is that they fit a range of results.
The words "worst possible" or "best possible" are sounding more than statements than judgements. "Perfect"/"Impeccable" contains the information that it not only contains no errors, it gives the impression that it *should* not contain errors.

The searched word should immediately inform the reader that if something is measured on a scale, this result *is the worst possible result*. Beyond fubar. We hit the rock bottom. A perfect screw-up.

EDIT: If there is no such word and I am stuck with "worst possible", that would be nice to know, too. But I must admit, the "unworsenable score" has something...

Comment: I think Beckett coined 'unworsenable'. But I'd be tempted to avoid it. What's wrong with 'worst possible'?

Comment: A  disastrous score.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you talk with other people, you mostly use judging statements like "perfect/excellent/very good/average/poor/awful/bad" to share the emotion. "Worst possible" is ok, but I find it does not find the right tone.

Comment: @Josh61 "Disastrous" could mean anything down from the worst possible note. The notes are judged in this case very strict from a linear scale, the rule of thumb is that more than 50% of errors is failed; there is much room left for "dis"improvement.

Comment: You could make some mention of Murphy's Law--everything that possibly could go wrong did.

Comment: "The lowest possible score"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest **nadir**.

[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nadir) defines this as (which includes the phrase "rock bottom" that you used):

> bottom, depths, lowest point, rock bottom, all-time low

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nadir) defines this as:

> the worst or lowest point of something

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nadir?s=t) defines this as:

> the lowest point; point of greatest adversity or despair.

There are [examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22scored%20a%20nadir%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22nadir%20score%22%20-liebman%20-%22root%20me%22) out there of the phrase "nadir score" being used to indicate the lowest score on a scale.  Here is [one example](http://www.safranlab.net/uploads/7/6/4/6/7646935/impact_message_inventory_manual.pdf):

> the IMI-C nadir score (the lowest scale score obtained by a particular patient)

Comment: Following Josh61's logics: nadir score? nadir is used in a different context: the lowest point in the fortunes of a person or organization.

Comment: @DariusMiliauskas Edited my answer, "nadir score" can be used for scores.

Comment: "nadir score" is currently the best try as answer. I know "nadir" from astronomy in contrast to zenith, but I think it is practically unknown in common language. "Unworsenable" is at least understandable at once.

Comment: I don't think naidr fits: it is the lowest /attained/ point, not the lowest /possible/ point: it clearly relates to a particular object/person, not a theoretical minimum. The use of /possible/ by the OP suggests to me that they have the latter in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The word **abysmal** is an extreme adjective (though perhaps has lost force because it is used in unmerited (!) situations). Acording to [Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary, © 2010 K Dictionaries Ltd. Copyright 2005, 1997, 1991 by Random House, Inc](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/abysmal) it means

> adj.
>
> 1. of or like an abyss; immeasurably deep or great: abysmal ignorance.
> 2. extremely or hopelessly bad or severe: abysmal weather.

Answer (score 1):

In the “[Deuce to Seven/Kansas City](http://web.comhem.se/~u70408099/ordlista.html#Dead)” variation of low-ball poker the pot is won, not by the best or highest poker hand as in most games, but rather by the lowest or worst one.  The perfect hand to have in that game is in fact the [worst poker hand possible](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=worst%20poker%20hand), which (with aces high) is a "seventy-five," an unsuited “7 high” hand comprised of a **7**, **5**, 4, 3, 2.

Such a “perfect” low hand is referred to as “[lock low](http://web.comhem.se/~u70408099/ordlista.html#/Large%20Bet)” and I think the “ultimate imperfection” notion of “[lock low](http://dictionary.pokerzone.com/Lock)” could easily be transferred to and understood in the context of test scores and serve as a suitable antonym for “ultimate perfection”: his/her score was “lock low” — s/he had a “lock-low score” of zero.

Unfortunately, as a result of spending too much time pursuing elusive lock low poker hands in college, many of us "drew" rock bottom, lock-low test scores instead!

Answer (score 1):

"**Pessimal**" is [the opposite of "optimal"](https://www.edwardtufte.com/bboard/q-and-a-fetch-msg?msg_id=0003uY). This is the only word I know of that has the exact meaning you seek of "worst possible"; "nadir" only means "worst actually achieved", which is unlikely to be 0%.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that he got none right, call it a *zero score*.

Answer (score 0):

**Meritless** would fit and is a signle word. If you're willing to accept more than a single word, I'd suggest more common and natural phrases like **without merit** or **with no redeeming features**.

Answer (score -1):

> corrupt - (of a text or a computer database or program) made
>   unreliable by errors or alterations.
>
> inoperative - not working or taking effect.

Comment: A corrupt score?

Comment: The question sounds "Antonym of “perfect, flawless” with the meaning that *everything* is faulty", and then "Example". The answer does not fit the given example in the question but it still fits the question, and can be used with other examples like "corrupt database".

Comment: Sorry, not ok. "Unreliable" or "corrupt" does not mean explicitly completely wrecked, only that it works only partially.

Answer (score -3):

> Why not-
>
> **[Imperfect](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/imperfect)** (adj.)
>
> 1. exhibiting or characterized by faults, mistakes, etc; defective
> 2. not complete or finished; deficient
>          - “***imperfect score***”