# What would be the best counterpart to the term "unimprovable"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

Something along the lines of "not capable of being brought lower than one's current point."

Considering `unimprovable` having the root `improve`, I am looking for a term that has the same effect from a word antonymous to `improve`.

Using a rock as an example, `unimprovable` in the sense I'm concerned with would be along the lines of "This rock can never be made better than it currently is, it is unimprovable."

I am looking for a term that would fit into "This rock can never be made worse than it currently is, it is ______"

Comment: Isn't  the antonym of *unimprovable* (not able to be improved) ***improvable*** (able to be improved)??

Comment: Improvable is an antonym, yes, but not quite the answer to the question. I'm looking more for the inverse form of the term. As improve's antonym in the above context would most closely be worsen, what I am looking for is more "unworsenable," but an actual word.

Comment: Hello Brandon. Welcome to EL&U. Your question is good, but it lacks clarity and therefore risks getting closed. I advise you to edit it and reword it so people don't get misled by the term `antonym`. An example of a situation where you want the word would benefit the post greatly.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I hope I worded it better. I've never posed a question in such a manner before, so exemplifying what I'm looking for was quite rough at first. Another complication is that there isn't really a well defined term I could find for the antonym of "improvable" either, in the general sense I'm looking for.

Comment: See Edwin's comment [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/antonym-of-perfect-flawless-with-the-meaning-that-everything-is-faulty/365649)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a term found in Indian literature that might fit:

**[undeteriorable](https://www.google.com/search?q=undeteriorable&rlz=1C1CHBF_enIN820IN820&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUiIePwrXfAhXFh3AKHQzPBEAQ_AUIFCgB&biw=1536&bih=750)**

I can't say if this is used in the west, though. Dictionaries don't seem to list it.

Comment: Looking past the issue of its lack of use here, I would agree that "undeteriorable" is about the closest to this problem's solution. I suppose I was just hoping for something more succinct, but it is a very specific term to use.

Comment: I think the root word is common enough to enable you to get your meaning across, even if the derivative itself is rare. Good luck.